# Varaible Error Stored in Unbounded After Except

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function which tries to run a function multiple times. It logs each failure as a warning and then if it fails the maximum number of times should log it as an error and then raise the exception if exceptions are set to be raised. However, when it gets to the error log I'm getting an UnboundLocalError for `e`. How is this the case? I set it before the for loop and I know it's getting assigned because the warning logs are hit.

Function:

```
def repeat_calls(func: Callable, n_calls: int, raise_error: bool, error_msg: str, **kwargs):
    e = 'No exception yet'
    for ii in range(n_calls):
        try:
            func(**kwargs)
            return
        except BaseException as e:
            logging.warning(f'{ii+1} failure(s)! -> {error_msg}: {e}')

    logging.error(f'{n_calls} failure(s). Done trying. {error_msg}: {e}')
    if raise_error:
        raise e
```

Log tail:

```
Caching sift factors

2022-09-29 15:48:21,532 WARNING run_strategies.py 169 1 failure(s)! -> Caught exception in cache_shift_factor for may21_may21: cache_shift_factor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lambda_timout_seconds'
2022-09-29 15:48:21,533 WARNING run_strategies.py 169 2 failure(s)! -> Caught exception in cache_shift_factor for may21_may21: cache_shift_factor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lambda_timout_seconds'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_strategies.py", line 1010, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "run_strategies.py", line 403, in cache_luca_signals_cli
    binding_flow_ratio=binding_flow_ratio, n_sf_snapshots=n_sf_snapshots, n_days=n_days)
  File "run_strategies.py", line 281, in cache_analysis_period
    **kwargs)
  File "run_strategies.py", line 171, in repeat_calls
    logging.error(f'{n_calls} failure(s). Done trying. {error_msg}: {e}')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Try `except BaseException as e2:` and adding  `e = e2` to that block.

Comment: That does indeed work. Thanks for the advice. What's the reason for that assignment being necessary? Is it just because during the except block e becomes that error which is considered local to that scope so when the block is exited garbage cleanup no longer sees any references to it?

Comment: I imagine something like that; some Python guru should be able to give a clearer explanation than I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer (per Scott Hunter)

Put except BaseException as e2: and adding e = e2 to that block.

Some local scope issue causes garbage cleanup to remove the variable without that assignment as far as I can tell.